# How does string.unpack work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Can someone explain why how the result for the following unpack is computed?

```
"aaa".unpack('h2H2')               #=> ["16", "61"]
```

In binary, 'a' = 0110 0001.  I'm not sure how the 'h2' can become 16 (0001 0000) or 'H2' can become 61 (0011 1101).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not 16 - it is showing 1 and then 6.  h is giving the hex value of each nibble, so you get 0110 (6), then 0001 (1), depending on whether its the high or low bit you're looking at.  Use the high nibble first and you get 61, which is hex for 97 - the value of 'a'

Answer (score 6):

Check out the Programming Ruby [reference](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-unpack) on unpack. Here's a snippet:

> Decodes str (which may contain binary
> data) according to the format string,
> returning an array of each value
> extracted. The format string consists
> of a sequence of single-character
> directives, summarized in Table 22.8
> on page 379. Each directive may be
> followed by a number, indicating the
> number of times to repeat with this
> directive. An asterisk ("*") will
> use up all remaining elements. The
> directives sSiIlL may each be followed
> by an underscore ("_") to use the
> underlying platform's native size for
> the specified type; otherwise, it uses
> a platform-independent consistent
> size. Spaces are ignored in the format
> string. See also  Array#pack   on page
> 286.

And the relevant characters from your example:

> H     Extract hex nibbles from each character (most significant first).
>
> h     Extract hex nibbles from each character (least significant first).

Answer (score 2):

The hex code of char `a` is 61.

Template `h2` is a hex string (low nybble first), `H2` is the same with high nibble first.

Also see the [perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html).