# How encode sequence of bytes into ruby string with characters

Tags: ruby, string, encode, hex

How encode sequence of bytes from ruby string into ruby string human-readable characters?

This is input string:

`"\x127\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\xA2\x8F"`

So how parse this string into array with bytes,

and encode every element from array to ASCII character?

P.S. However, I can't find a way to roundtrip from bytes back to an array. I tried to use Array.pack with the U* option, but that doesn't work for multibyte characters.

Comment: Please give example of what you mean by "human-readable" (I can read your example just fine if I am to understand it as a Ruby string). Also, it is a good idea to show some code that you have so far, otherwise it takes more effort to answer your question (and less people will think to do so).

Comment: may be this method will help you - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-unpack .. But How I don't know.. :)

Comment: Sorry to cast a close on this. I think if you knew what yu were looking for, you probably would not have needed to ask the question in the first place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does string.unpack work in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131811/how-does-string-unpack-work-in-ruby)

Comment: `"string\xaa".each_byte.map {|b| "%c" % b }`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ, please move your response from comment to answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @bmalets can't because your post has been put *on hold*, so all answers are blocked from that. Expand your post with additional info/example. and ask moderators to reopen the post.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ, it's open now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
"string\xaa".each_byte.map {|b| "%c(%x)" % [ b, b ] }.join( ' ' )
# => "s(73) t(74) r(72) i(69) n(6e) g(67) ª(aa)"
```